# Is there a term to describe all non-root nodes in a tree?

Tags: graph, terminology

Root covers the root, what are the rest of the nodes collectively called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in the real world: branches and leaves

They are all child nodes (of the root or some other node).

Comment: i'm looking for a term that would encompass both branches and leaves.  I'm hoping there is something better than 'non-root node'.

Comment: well all non-root nodes are child nodes

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem -- I was creating a base class for all non-root nodes and was looking for a succinct name. Here's what I came up with (and I realize none of these is perfect):

- `NonRootNode` -- this is a bit clumsy, but certainly descriptive
- `ChildNode` -- short, but potentially misleading
- `ParentedNode` -- I like this one
- `NestedNode` -- might work depending on the context

Answer (score 2):

In the middle they're called branches. On the very ends, they're leaves.

Answer (score 1):

```
        R
       / \
      B   L
     / \
    L   B
       /
      L
```

R is root, B are branches L are leaves

Comment: is there a term that covers branches and leaves but excludes the root?  in other words, any node that's not a root.

Comment: @glenn l. Yes they're called children